# JavaFX does not render properly, but my basic code is probably wrong

Tags: animation, javafx, mouse, render, rectangles

I was coding a simple shape-collision-detector, but I noticed the rectangle which I move using the mouse vanishes in some window's areas.
I can't figure out why.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B2gY.gif) you can see the video and below the code I used.
Any advice?

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setWidth(150);
r.setHeight(150);

Group root = new Group(r, e, boh);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);

scene.setOnMouseDragged(ev -> {
    r.setX(ev.getX() - r.getWidth() / 2);
    r.setY(ev.getY() - r.getHeight() / 2);
});
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. Advice here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/CollisionDectionFx/blob/master/src/collisiondection/FXMLDocumentController.java

Answer (score -2):

I solved by placing another Rectangle as background.